# Архитектура web API на Java

Tags: java, архитектура, rest

Подскажите, пож, этапы создания грамотного АПИ на JAVA.(Или ткните в какойто мануал, т.к. серфинг в гугле удовлетворяющего ответа не принес)

Как мне видится схема построения апи -

-закидываем на вход XML, JSON, curl (в идеале и то и то) через HTTP 
   -демаршалим на сущности
   -настраиваем JDBC(JPA) коннектимся к БД
   -из десериализованных сущностей формируем запрос к БД
   -получаем ответ , сериализуем в XML/JSON
   -возвращаем ответ

Интересно по инструментарию, что оптимально юзать на каждом из этапов.
Удобнее ли для настройки коннекта с базой использовать ORM

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какого рода API вы хотите реализовать? Ваше описание больше похоже на CRUD к базе данных.

Comment: Да Вы правы. Нужно что-то в роде публичного АПИ, которое смогут дергать сторонние пользователи / комплексы

Comment: Грамотный АПИ начинается с API vs. АПИ и Java vs. JAVA

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Из постановки вопроса вырисовывается обычное веб-приложение, которое с одной стороны работает с json/xml через HTTP, а с другой ползает в базу данных.

Получается 3 каноничных слоя: web-сервис, бизнес-логика и слой хранения данных. Эта схема, на самом деле, широко рассмотрена со всех сторон в интернетах. Посмотрим еще раз.

### Web-сервис

Это собственно и есть внешний API, все остальное - детали реализации. Чтобы принимать запросы по HTTP потребуется web-сервер, наиболее популярные в среде Java это [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/). Я бы для начала остановился на Jetty, его легко запускать с минимумом конфигурации и легко встроить в ваше приложение, если потребуется.

Далее нужно определиться с концепцией web-сервиса: будет ли это один из видов [RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80) ([SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [XML-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), [JSON-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC), [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/), [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/)) или [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST):

- RPC легче для восприятия, так как похожи на обычный вызов локального метода, но они прячут всю магию под капотом и, как правило, используют свои форматы передачи данных (на основе xml/json или бинарные). API на основе RPC легко быстро спрототипировать: обычно вы описываете обычный интерфейс, реализуете его серверную часть, все остальное сделают за вас и даже сгенерируют заглушки для клиентского кода на определенном наборе языков программирования.
- REST строится вокруг идеи передачи состояния объектов между клиентом и сервером, то есть оперирует объектами, а не действиями. Такой API хорошо ложится на CRUD, но требует тщательного продумывания для более сложных кейсов. Он достаточно низкоуровневый в том отношении, что вы сами определяете форматы данных, обработку ошибок, что добавляет сложности. Но все это при правильном подходе позволяет легче масштабировать web-сервис в дальнейшем.

Исходя из ваших требований (CRUD-операции и одновременная поддержка JSON и XML), вам, вероятно, больше подойдет REST. Для Java существует спецификация [JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html), описывающая стандартный способ создания REST-сервисов и ряд её реализаций: [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html), [Resteasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/). Общая идея такова, что вы пишите обычные классы, принимающие и возвращающие ваши объекты, развешиваете аннотации и веб-сервис готов:

```
@Path("/api")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public class MyApi {

    @GET
    @Path("/foo/{id}")
    public Foo getFooById(@PathParam("id") Long id) { ... }

    @POST
    @Path("/foo")
    public Foo createFooById(Foo foo) { ... }
}
```

И вот мы уже можем через `POST` и `GET` создавать и получать экземпляры класса `Foo`. Маршаллинг в json/xml и обратно нам прозрачно сделает библиотека Jackson.

## Бизнес-логика

С этим все просто, это ваши классы, которые делают что-то полезное над передаваемыми вверх-вниз объектами: валидируют или дополняют данные, бросают ошибки, создают уведомления, взаимодействуют с файловой системой. Если коротко, выполняют непосредственную работу.

Возможно, для удобства управления вы захотите поместить классы в какой-либо DI контейнер: [Spring](https://spring.io/), [EJB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) (только, если речь об энтерпрайзе) или связать чем-то более легковесным вроде [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted).

## Хранение данных

Про persistence-слой вы также без труда найдете массу информации. Выделите отдельные классы (обычно из называют DAO - Data Access Objects), которые будут класть и доставать объекты из БД. Тут вам в помощь JDBC, JPA, ORM-ы. Главное - представлять, что тот же Hibernate тяжеловесный и достаточно сложный, и, если речь идет о десятке классов/таблиц, проще будет покорячиться с JDBC (жизнь облегчат Spring-овый [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) или симпатичная библиотечка [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/)). Еще можете глянуть [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) - это такая глобальная абстракция над любыми хранилищами (вдруг завтра вы решите хранить данные не в БД, а на другом сервере, доступном через REST).

Еще один момент: не стоит поддаваться искушению отдавать экземпляры классы, которые ORM вытащит из БД сразу в REST. На уровне веб-сервиса переложите их в транспортные DTO-шки. Это избавит вас от боли в дальнейшем. Если лень перекладывать руками, можете попробовать какой-нибудь [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) (но его придется конфигурировать в свою очередь XML-ем).

## Синяя изолента

Посмотрим, какой выходит стек технологий:

- Web-server: Jetty/Tomcat/Grizzly
- Rest-endpoint: Jackson и Jersey/CXF/Resteasy
- DI: Spring/Guice
- Persistence: JDBC/JPA/ORM + опционально Spring JDBC/Spring Data/JDBI

Все это, конечно, нужно обложить логами. Сейчас популярно SLF4J + Logback. По вкусу - сбор метрик, например, [Codahale Metrics](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/).

Из описанных компонентов можно собрать как классическое web-приложение, завернутое в war-файл, которое можно развернуть в сервлет-контейнере (Jetty, Tomcat) или на application-сервере, так и standalone-приложение, со встроенным веб-сервером, которое можно таскать с места на место и запускать из командной строки.

Если вы захотите пойти по второму пути (сейчас модно писать независимые микросервисы) стоит попробовать [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) ([Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/)) или [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/). Эти инструменты сгенерируют всю необходимую обвязку, чтобы вы могли сосредоточиться на написании бизнес-логики.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ушло в избранное)